# Replace a column of number array with string

Tags: pyspark

I have 2 dataframes. I am trying to map DF1 with DF2 to form output as below:

DF1

```
Username| TeamId
------------------
UserA   | [1,2,3] 
UserB   | [2] 
UserC   | [3,4]
```

DF2

```
Id| Teamname
------------------
1 | IT
2 | Accounting 
3 | HR
4 | Finance
```

Result DF:

```
Username| TeamId  | Teamnames
--------------------------------------
UserA   | [1,2,3] | IT,Accounting,HR
UserB   | [2]     | Accounting
UserC   | [3,4]   | HR,Finance
```

DF2 is a small dataset with 20 rows only. I have tried convert it as a dictionary and then map to DF1.col('TeamId'). Should I use dictionary or I should join these 2 dataframe instead?

Answer (score 0):

there's another way to create array of structs using `df2`, and then filter that based on `teamid` array.

here's an example

```py
# create array of structs using all rows of df2
id_name_sdf = data1_sdf. \
    groupBy(func.lit(1).alias('gk')). \
    agg(func.collect_list(func.struct('id', 'teamname')).alias('id_name_arr'))

# +---+-------------------------------------------------+
# |gk |id_name_arr                                      |
# +---+-------------------------------------------------+
# |1  |[{1, IT}, {2, Accounting}, {3, HR}, {4, Finance}]|
# +---+-------------------------------------------------+

# join with df1 for further processing
data2_sdf. \
    withColumn('gk', func.lit(1)). \
    join(id_name_sdf, 'gk', 'left'). \
    withColumn('res', func.filter('id_name_arr', lambda x: func.exists('teamid', lambda y: y == x.id))). \
    withColumn('teamnames', func.transform('res', lambda a: a.teamname)). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+--------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------+
# |gk |username|teamid   |id_name_arr                                      |res                                |teamnames           |
# +---+--------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------+
# |1  |UserA   |[1, 2, 3]|[{1, IT}, {2, Accounting}, {3, HR}, {4, Finance}]|[{1, IT}, {2, Accounting}, {3, HR}]|[IT, Accounting, HR]|
# |1  |UserB   |[2]      |[{1, IT}, {2, Accounting}, {3, HR}, {4, Finance}]|[{2, Accounting}]                  |[Accounting]        |
# |1  |UserC   |[3, 4]   |[{1, IT}, {2, Accounting}, {3, HR}, {4, Finance}]|[{3, HR}, {4, Finance}]            |[HR, Finance]       |
# +---+--------+---------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+--------------------+
```

I've retained all interim columns for better understanding, but you can only keep the ones required. `res` is created using `filter` and `exists` functions. `exists` will check if the array of structs has the `id` available in the `teamid` array. `filter` drops rows where `exists` returns false.